# How to convert \ using newtonsoft.json.linq.serializeobject in vb.net httprequest?

Tags: vb.net, http, json.net, suitecrm

I have a JSON object created using Newtonsoft JObject but I get a bad request error when I try to submit it if any of the properties have spaces, slashes, etc.

```
updatestring = "date=2/14/2019"
Dim jobjattr As New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject(
    New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("description", "test"),
    New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("source", updatestring)
)
Dim jobjdat As New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject(
    New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("type", "synch_log"),
    New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("id", "6278042e-ed64-0418-a651-5c574dc4f12b"),
    New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("attributes", jobjattr)
)
Dim jobj As New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject(New Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty("data", jobjdat))

Dim jsonserializersettings As New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
jsonserializersettings.StringEscapeHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
Dim stringReq = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobj, jsonserializersettings)

Dim byteData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringReq)
httprequest.ContentLength = byteData.Length
Dim postreqstream As System.IO.Stream = .GetRequestStream()
postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
postreqstream.Close()
```

incoming jobj = {"data":{"type":"synch_log","id":"6278042e-ed64-0418-a651-5c574dc4f12b","attributes":{"description":"test","source":"date=2/14/2019"}}}

after serialzation byteData still = {"data":{"type":"synch_log","id":"6278042e-ed64-0418-a651-5c574dc4f12b","attributes":{"description":"test","source":"date=2/14/2019"}}}

I would expect the / to be escaped.
any text string works fine
I have also tried jsonserializer settings as Default and EscapeHtml but with the same result.

Other characters cause the same eror.  "datetoday" posts correctly but "date=today" and "date today" result in a 400 bad request error

The closest answer I have found is that maybe the object is being double escaped but I can't see how that would be.

Comment: You could specify a `DateFormatString` as a parameter in `JsonSerializerSettings`. I think it would be better if you used a specialized class object to help you define your properties values and serialize the class as a whole (using `DateTime` values for dates).

Comment: unfortunately it is not just a datetime issue.  The field is free form text so the date was the first thing that caused an issue but a user could put anything else in there that also contained slashes, spaces, etc.

Comment: What is the code on the server side?

Comment: Is a [URLEncoded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode) string acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.  Brian, you led me in the right direction.  I failed to mention that it is an API call to SuiteCRM but your question got me thinking to look on the server side and it turns out there is an unresolved bug with the V8 API.  I just assumed it was my code.

[github bug report](https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/pull/6901)